# Problema com button

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho dois buttons, um para ativar categoria e outro pra desativar, cada um com seu layout. Preciso alternar entre os dois, quando um ativa, ele muda no banco pra ativado e fica sendo exibido enquanto o outro não aparece e vice versa. Porem não estou entendendo a logica de como fazer isso. Sei que é com ajax, pra um altera.php por exemplo.

```
<button class="on-default remove-row text-warning"><i=class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"><i></button>

<button class="on-default remove-row text-success"><i=class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"><i></button>
```

Alguém pode dar uma força?

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma *class* no css para esconder o button:

```
.isHidden{ display: none}
```

Adicione uma *class* para identificar os buttons:

*Exemplo:*

```
<button class="button-active on-default remove-row text-warning"><i=class=" fa fa-thumbs-o-down"><i></button>
```

Como o Ajax, verifique se a categoria está ativa, se não estiver, você vai no ***button*** e esconde ele. 
Exemplo:

```
$(".button-active").addClass('isHidden');
```

Caso a categoria esteja ativa, você remove a *class*:

```
$(".button-active").removeClass('isHidden');
```

Comment: certo, mas pra fazer isso verificar no banco de dados primeiro antes de alterar?

Comment: eu montei certinho no php e ele altera mas ele dá refresh na pagina, por isso quero no ajax

Comment: Basta verificar se a categoria está ativa com o Ajax. Esse site mostra como usar o Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.
Com o retorno da consulta Ajax você decide o que fazer com o button, conforme coloquei acima.

Comment: certo, vou tentar aqui, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Usando Jquery pode usar o metodo `.toggle()` :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button style="display:block;" onclick="toggle_button()" class="on-default remove-row text-warning" id="bon">ON</button>
<button style="display:none;" onclick="toggle_button()" class="on-default remove-row text-success" id="boff">OFF</button>

<script>

function toggle_button(val) {
    $('#bon').toggle();
    $('#boff').toggle();
}

</script>
```

```js
function toggle_button(val) {
 $('#bon').toggle();
 $('#boff').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="display:block;" onclick="toggle_button()" class="on-default remove-row text-warning" id="bon">ON</button>
<button style="display:none;" onclick="toggle_button()" class="on-default remove-row text-success" id="boff">OFF</button>
```